# EntityFramework Fluent API create Relationships without Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to create a relationship between two classes using only **Ids**?
In this example I'm trying to create a **One-to-Many** relationship between `Company`and `Employee` (One `Company` has many `Employee`)

Here's my code:

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

Using **Fluent API** I'm able to create the relationship, as long as I create a Navigation Property. I'm looking for a way to relate those two classes by `Company.Id` and `Employee.CompanyId` without any navigation properties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have navigation properties how do you want to use them in relation in your code? Or do you just want EF to create the foreign key constraints for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can see which might come close at least to a "relationship without navigation properties" is creating the FK contraint in the database with a hand-written migration, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class CreateCompanyAndEmployee : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "Companies",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    CompanyName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100)
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "Employees",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    CompanyId = c.Guid(nullable: false)
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddForeignKey("Employees", "CompanyId", "Companies", "Id");
        CreateIndex("Employees", "CompanyId");
    }

    //...
}
```

Since you have no navigation properties you must use joins with LINQ-to-Entities if you ever want to load for example a company including all related employees, like this for instance:

```
var companiesWithEmployees = context.Companies
    .GroupJoin(context.Employees,
        company => company.Id,
        employee => employee.CompanyId,
        (company, employees) => new
        {
            Company = company,
            Employees = employees
        })
    .ToList();
```

You always must specify the property `employee.CompanyId` explicitly that represents the foreign key in such joins. EF is not aware that the `CompanyId` is a foreign key property. It's just an ordinary scalar property in the EF model without any relationship meaning.

`companiesWithEmployees` would be a collection of anonymous objects. Each object contains a `Company` entity and a collection `IEnumerable<Employee>` of the employees related with that company.

However, I fail to see the benefit of avoiding navigation properties.